# How many times called the function calculate? İn C

Tags: c, function

I have one question.
I want to write a program with fibonacci, but i have a problem.

"Every time the function is called from the main function, it should print out how many times it has been called"

I try add counter, but every time counter is 1. Thx

Comment: You really should show us the code you are using. However, you probably need to make your 'count' variable `static` - then its value will be maintained across function calls.

Comment: Share your code and we might be able to help.

Comment: Let us see your code :-). Global variable might help or ```static```.

Comment: "Every time the function is called **from the main function**" fortunately we are in C rather than C++ else the limitation associated to the end of the sentence will not be easy to do

Comment: What code do you want us to address?  You've shown us *nothing*.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the static variable or you can pass the count variable for each call. The below one is for static variable case

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int fib(int n) 
{ static int count = 0; 
  count++; 
  printf("%d", count); 
   if (n <= 1) 
      return n; 
   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
} 

int main () 
{ 
  int n = 9; 
  printf("%d", fib(n)); 
  getchar(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i want to fibonacci, but this program output is : '12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182838485868788899091929394959697989910010110210310410510610710810934' not only one value

Answer (score 0):

Your initial attempt of adding a counter and it always being 1 tells me that you're a beginner.  One very important concept you will need to get a handle on is "scope".  When you create a local variable in a function, the variable gets allocated from the stack each time the function is called and is considered "in scope" for the duration of the function until you return.  When you return from the function, the memory allocated for the variable is released and is no longer considered "in scope".  Without specifically telling the compiler that you want the variable to hang around (using the `static` keyword), you are not guaranteed to get the same chunk of memory, and even if you did get the same chunk of memory, it's very likely that some other function has used it and destroyed whatever value was there.

So to answer your question specifically, you should use the `static` keyword in the variable declaration for your counter such as `static int counter = 0;` with an initial value of 0.